# Trouble Selecting Table View Rows

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am having trouble selecting table view row in `didSelectRowAt`/`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. The function is never called.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
           print("Row: ", indexPath.row)
          if(indexPath.row == 9)
          {
             print("Row 9 Selected")
          }
}
```

Based on various Stack Overflow articles, here is what I have tried:

1. I have tried "didSelectRowAt" and "didSelectRowAtIndexPath"
2. I have set the table view's delegate to self using its outlet
3. Table View Settings:
   -Selection: Single Selection
   -Editing: No Selection During Editing
   -Interaction: User Interaction Enabled
4. Individual Cell Settings:
   -Interaction: User Interaction Enabled
5. I set tableview.allowsInteraction to true in code as well as storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be with  `_`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
```

Check [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614877-tableview)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using NSIndexPath instead of IndexPath

Answer (score 0):

check delegate value using break point either it is nil or not

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   // Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set an @IBOutlet to the tableView in you ViewController and set as it's delegate and dataSource.
Something like this :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

And implements the UITableViewDataSource protocol too.
Or you can too in the Interface Builder set the ViewController as it's delegate and dataSource  and avoid to set manually in code like above.

If you have more than one tableView I your code than please try to mention different names for every tableView and then call the delegate with particular tableView name.

Also you have mentioned 3rd point here “Single Selection -Editing: No Selection During Editing”. This means if you try to edit anything in tableView there will be no selection please try to replace this and then check if you get some result.
Because if set “tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = false” then it will not allow you selections in tableView.